# error 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found Xcode 9

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

i have some error after building ionic app iOS version and when open it with Xcode 9 i got error 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found i didn't understand why in fact this is first time i got this error

Answer (score 1):

Same was happening for me. The following allowed the project to build:

The "Cordova" folder isn't getting copied into the project during `cordova platform add ios`.

So, you'll have to copy the "Cordova" source folder into your project manually. But you'll have to download the **ios** source packages from github first, which is located at:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios

After downloading the "cordova-ios-master.zip" package and unzipping it, copy the folder named "CordovaLib" into your project next to the Xcode project file:

```
PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/ios/PROJECT_NAME
PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/ios/PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj
PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/ios/PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace
PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/ios/cordova
PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/ios/CordovaLib   <------- here
PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/ios/ios.json
PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/ios/platform_www
PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/ios/pods-debug.xcconfig
PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/ios/pods-release.xcconfig
PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms/ios/www
```